# Can a bad GPU cause bad preformance with flash games?

Tags: flash

I use flash for some time now and my GPU broke down recently so i have to use one with 128Mb. Anyway, now when i make some games i see some weird bugs in preformance, could this be the cause of it?

Answer (score 0):

may be.. but see this is how flash or air would do when you use GPU or CPU and Direct..

There are 2 components in the display pipeline

1 Rendering 
2 Compositing

There are 3 render Modes are possible in Flash/AIR
1-CPU
2-GPU
3-DIRECT

With CPU, BOTH Compositing and Rendering are handled by the CPU or software
With GPU, Compositing is handled by the GPU i.e hardware. Rendering is still handled by CPU or software

DIRECT is the opposite of GPU mode in that Compositing is handled by the CPU or software and rendering is handled by the GPU i.e hardware.

GPU mode benefits most from partial blitting, CPU mode from stage blitting and benefits from DIRECT mode come only if targeting Stage3D, either directly or indirectly via a framework like Starling or Away3D.

Hope that gives you some idea :)